# Get affected records with mongoose update command

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I get ids of affected records inside database when executing mongoose update command with multi:true option?

```
    MyModel.update({ age: { $gt: 18 } }, { oldEnough: true }, { multi: true }, function (err, raw) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
    });
```

This will return number of affected documents, but how can I know their ids without running another query inside database?

Comment: Try `raw.map(x => x._id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update operation with or without the `multi: true` option returns a [`WriteResult`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult) which does not have a property containing such details. Only various counts.

When it comes to mongoose as per [their documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) you only get and `err` and `rawResponse` in their callback on success:

> The callback function receives (err, rawResponse).
>
> err is the error if any occurred rawResponse is the full response from
>   Mongo

So you basically get the `WriteResult` from mongo nothing more nothing less.

So **no** you can not get a convenient list of the updated `_id` although you could probably do something with the `post` update middleware where you can run the `filter` part of the update and store the _ids somewhere I guess for audit etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using post middleware but the problem is when filter part of the update doesn't contain _ids, as in the proposed example.